# Source code to class diagram generation

Tags: uml, models

How can I generate a class diagram and other related modeling diagrams from source code ?

I am open to any tool (Eclipse plug-in etc) but does Netbeans has a plugin for it too?

Answer (score 4):

I've used [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) for a Java project, and I liked that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse with a UML plugin to reverse the java code.

Once it is reverse you just need to export the image to a PNG, JPG format (I recommend PNG because the picture is better). Copy then this model export picture into the netbeans project. Some of my friends are doing it and it works well. They prefer netbeans to Eclipse for Java EE integration with Glassfish, so they only use Eclipse for the graphical power of GEF/EMF in order to get nice diagrams and still use their favorite IDE Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice tool: http://java2uml.gforge.enseeiht.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I've used ArgoUML for modeling.  It is a good open-source project and i've found it to be a good, cheap alternative to commercial products.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone:

try [ObjectAid UML Explorer](http://www.objectaid.com/).. i am using eclipse IDE.. i find this very helpful..